# Understanding what $\displaystyle \lim\sup_{x \to a, x \in E} f(x)$ means

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, epsilon-delta, limsup-and-liminf

I recently learned of the following extension to the definition of a limit: Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$, let $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, let $a$ be a limit point of $S$, and let $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\lim_{x \to a \\ x \in S } f(x) = L$$

means the following: For each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that
$$x \in S \text{ and } |x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.$$

(I assume this definition extends similarly for general metric spaces.) I am now trying to understand the analogous extension for limit sup's and lim inf's. To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior):

> There is a notion of lim sup and lim inf for functions defined on a metric space whose relationship to limits of real-valued functions mirrors that of the relation between the lim sup, lim inf, and the limit of a real sequence. Take a metric space $X$, a subspace $E$ contained in $X$, and a function $f : E \rightarrow R$. Define, for any limit point a $a$ of $E$,
> \begin{align} \limsup_{x \to a} f(x) := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\sup \big\{f(x):x \in E \cap B (a;\epsilon) \setminus \{a\} \big\}\right) \hspace{3cm} (1) \end{align}
>
> and
> $$ \liminf_{x \to a} f(x) := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\inf \big\{f(x):x \in E \cap B (a;\epsilon) \setminus \{a\} \big\}\right) \hspace{3.3cm} (2) $$
> where $B(a;\epsilon)$ denotes the metric ball of radius $\epsilon$ about $a$.

My first question is: In the context of the setting described above, do $\displaystyle \lim\sup_{x \to a \\ x \in E} f(x) = L$ and $\displaystyle \lim\sup_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ mean the same thing? (And similarly for $\lim\inf$?). My question comes from my reading of Dini numbers in Stein and Shakarchi's *Real Analysis*. They define
$$D^{+}(F)(x) := \lim \sup_{h \to 0, \\ h > 0} \Delta_h(F)(x),  \hspace{3cm} (3) $$
where $\Delta_h(F)(x) := \frac{F(x + h) - F(x)}{h}$ (where $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), and similarly for the other three Dini numbers. I just want to ensure that I fully understand what this means. Does $(3)$ translate to the following?
\begin{align*}
    \lim \sup_{h \to 0, \\ h > 0} \Delta_h(F)(x) &:=  \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \left(\sup \left\{\Delta_h(F)(x): x \in (0,\infty) \cap (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \setminus \{0\}  \right\}\right) \\[4pt]
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \left(\sup \left\{\Delta_h(F)(x): x \in (0,\epsilon) \right\}\right) \quad ?
\end{align*}

(I take it that $h > 0$ means that $E = (0,\infty)$ in this case?)

Comment: In fact, you can define a notion of $\limsup_{x\to \mathcal{F}} f(x)$ for any filter $\mathcal{F}$ on a domain $E$ and a function $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$, and the definition goes very similarly: $\limsup_{x \to \mathcal{F}} f(x) = \inf \{ \sup(f(S)) \mid S \in \mathcal{F} \}$.  And if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{F}$ then this is equal to $\inf \{ \sup(f(S)) \mid S \in \mathcal{B} \}$.  That allows for generalizing to things like $\limsup_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and even...

Comment: defining the upper Riemann integral as the $\limsup$ of a net where the domain is partitions of the interval, ordered by refinement, and the values of the net are $\sum f(x_i^*) \Delta x_i$.

Comment: The above would then be the special case of where $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $a$ is a limit point of $S$, and the filter is the filter with basis $\{ S \cap (a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon) \mid \varepsilon > 0 \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question,  $\displaystyle\limsup_{x\to a;x\in E}f(x)$ is usually defined as (1) in your post. So $\displaystyle\limsup_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\displaystyle\limsup_{x\to a;x\in E}f(x)$ are trivially equivalent in your context.

<s>Note that if $a$ is a limit point of $S$, then for small enough $\epsilon>0$, you have</s> *[Incorrected remark deleted.]*

For your second question, both of your interpretations are incorrect. Be careful that $x$ is a fixed number(!) in the definition of $D^+(F)(x)$.

What you should have is:
$$
D^+(F)(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\big(\sup\{\Delta_h(F)(x): h\in(0,\epsilon)\}\big)
$$
which is the same as
$$
D^+(F)(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\big(\sup\{\Delta_h(F)(x): h\in(0,+\infty)\cap(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\}\big)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, I had the roles of $x$ and $h$ mixed up! And good point about the case where $a$ is a limit point of $S$.

Comment: @Leonidas: you are welcome. I am glad that it is helpful.

Comment: On second thought, I don't understand why $a$ being a limit point of $S$ implies that $E \cap B(a; \epsilon) \setminus \{a\} = B(a;\epsilon) \setminus \{a\}$ for small enough $\epsilon > 0$. Wouldn't this fail if, e.g., $a$ were a point on the boundary of $E$?

Comment: @Leonidas: Thanks. I was probably thinking about something else. That was my mistake. Let me fix that.

Comment: @Leonidas: I deleted the incorrect remark. An easy counterexample is that $(0,+\infty)\cap (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\setminus\{0\}\neq (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\setminus\{0\}$ for any $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification!